# "Format Exception Unhandled" in the following Windows Phone 7.1 program

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am currently making a small application for a [BMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) calculation. The program compiles fine, but I get a run time error of

> Format Exception Unhandled

in this line:

```
height = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
```

The line is a part of the function:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{ 
    float height;

    height = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    height = height*height;
}
```

Comment: So what's in textBox1.Text? Is it float shaped? Do you need to parse using an appropriate culture?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what's *in* the text box when you parse it. Perhaps it's empty, or the user's typed something like "fred". You should always assume that the input *could* be invalid:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 { 
    float height;

    if (!float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out height))
    {
        // Indicate to the user that the input is invalid, and stop processing
        // at this point. For example, you may want to highlight the textbox with
        // a red box. Return at the end of the block.
    }

    // It parsed correctly: continue...
    height = height*height;
    ...
}
```

(This would probably be structured slightly differently in an MVVM approach, but you'd still want to use [`float.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t.aspx) to *test* the user input before accepting it.)